# MATLAB event handler not called during while-loop

Tags: matlab

I have an ActiveX handle for a motorcontroller (h_TDC) which lets me register a few events. I want to make use of the 'MoveComplete'-Event.
In my main function I loop until a flag is switched. I want to set the flag in my eventhandler, which I have registered earlier. It is a nested function, so that it shares the same workspace, where the flag is.

It seems as though the events are fired correctly, but handled only after the while-loop, UNLESS I plot something, e.g. with imshow. This doesn't make sense to me.
How can I make the handling "interruptive" without plotting during the loop?

If I dont use imshow the script terminates after MAX_ITER. If I use imshow the handler terminates it earlier (as wished)

```
function Blubb
    MAX_ITER = 100;
    move_completed = false;
    ....
    h_moveComplete = @MyMoveCompleteHandler;
    h_TDC.registerevent({'MoveComplete' h_moveComplete});  % h_TDC is our activeX handle
    figure;
    while ~move_completed && i < MAX_ITER
        .....
        imshow(blubb)  %<-- without this the handler is executed only after while-loop
    end

        function MyMoveCompleteHandler(varargin)
            move_completed = true;
        end
end
```

Comment: Try [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html)

Comment: drawnow helped. Thanks alot excaza!